# PDFBox - Issue with generating PDF from a image

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to generate a PDF from images of type JPEG, BMP but i am gettng part of the image on the right always getting cut off. I am using one of the default windows picture Sunset.jpg.

Below is the code:

```
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import javax.imageio.stream.FileImageInputStream;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.COSVisitorException;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessFile;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.edit.PDPageContentStream;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDCcitt;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDJpeg;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDPixelMap;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDXObjectImage;

    public class ImageToPDF 
    {
        public void createPDFFromImage( String file, String image) throws IOException, COSVisitorException
        {
            PDDocument doc = null;
            try
            {
                doc = new PDDocument();
                PDPage page = new PDPage();
                doc.addPage( page );
                PDXObjectImage ximage = null;
                if( image.toLowerCase().endsWith( ".jpg" ) || image.toLowerCase().endsWith( ".jpeg" ))
                {        
                    BufferedImage awtImage = ImageIO.read( new File( image ) );             
            ximage = new PDJpeg(doc, awtImage, 0 );
                }
                else if (image.toLowerCase().endsWith(".tif") || image.toLowerCase().endsWith(".tiff"))
                {
                     ximage = new PDCcitt(doc, new RandomAccessFile(new File(image),"r"));
                }
                else
                {
                         BufferedImage awtImage = new BufferedImage(1000, 800, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);             
                     awtImage = ImageIO.read(new FileImageInputStream(new File( image )));                              
                     ximage = new PDPixelMap(doc, awtImage);
                }
                System.out.println(" Width of the image.... "+ximage.getWidth());
                PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);            
                contentStream.drawImage( ximage, 20, 20 );
                contentStream.close();
                doc.save( file );
           }
           finally
           {
                if( doc != null )
                {
                    doc.close();
                }
           }
       }

       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
            ImageToPDF app = new ImageToPDF();
            try
            {
                 app.createPDFFromImage( "C:\\test1.pdf", "C:\\Sunset.jpg");                        
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }
```

}

Please help me in correcting what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to your question here? If yes them please do share it as i am facing the same issue.

Comment: have you tried the latest? have you proper all the libraries usch as jemp and tempbox included??

Answer (score 10):

These code may helpful to you,It works.

```
    public void createPDFFromImage(String pdfFile, 
        List<String> imgList,int x, int y, float scale) throws IOException, COSVisitorException {
    // the document
    PDDocument doc = null;
    try {
        doc = new PDDocument();
        Iterator iter = imgList.iterator();
        int imgIndex=0;
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
            PDPage page = new PDPage();
            doc.addPage(page);

            BufferedImage tmp_image = ImageIO.read(new File(iter.next().toString()));
            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(tmp_image.getWidth(), tmp_image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);        
            image.createGraphics().drawRenderedImage(tmp_image, null);

            PDXObjectImage ximage = new PDPixelMap(doc, image);

            imgIndex++;


            PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(
                    doc, page,true,true);

            contentStream.drawXObject(ximage, x, y, ximage.getWidth()*scale, ximage.getHeight()*scale);

            contentStream.close();
        }
        doc.save(pdfFile);
    } finally {
        if (doc != null) {
            doc.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +10 for this code, I included the "contentStream.drawXObject" line into the code examples in PDFBox.

Comment: v2.0.0: drawXObject - "@deprecated Use drawImage or drawForm instead."

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered cropping your image to prevent it from being cut off ?

```
contentStream.drawImage( ximage, 20, 20, croppedWidth, croppedHeight );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to modify the drawImage statement as below:

```
content.drawImage(ximage,0 /*or your preferred indent*/,(700-ximage.getHeight()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below snippet and try:

**Import required:**

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
```

**Code Addition:**

```
PDXObjectImage image = new PDJpeg(pdfDoc, filePath));

float w = image.getWidth();
float h = image.getHeight();

PDPage page = new PDPage(new PDRectangle (w,h));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working routine (with PDFBox version 2.0.x) that adds a BufferedImage (e.g. a signature) onto a PDF document given as a Byte array. The result is a Byte array again.

```
    public static byte[] addBufferedImageIntoPdfPage(byte[] pdfDocumentData, BufferedImage imageToAdd, int pageNumber, int posX, int posY, float scaleImage) throws IOException
{
    PDDocument originalDocument = PDDocument.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfDocumentData));
    PDImageXObject pdImage = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(originalDocument, imageToAdd);
    PDPage page = originalDocument.getPage(pageNumber);
    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(originalDocument, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);

    // better method inspired by http://stackoverflow.com/a/22318681/535646
    contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, posX, posY, pdImage.getWidth() * scaleImage, pdImage.getHeight() * scaleImage);
    contentStream.close();
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    originalDocument.save(outputStream);
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!