# PDF Document is only half in width when converted a png image to pdf using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf-generation, document, pdfbox

I have used PDFBox to convert a png image to pdf document and i am successfully able to do that.

But i am encountering an issue in which the the pdf document only shows 50% width of the image (height is shown full).Please help me with this.

The code i am using is as follows:

```
public static void createPDFFromImage( String file, String image) throws IOException, COSVisitorException
    {
        PDDocument doc = null;
        try
        {
            doc = new PDDocument();
            PDPage page = new PDPage();
            doc.addPage( page );
            PDXObjectImage ximage = null;
            if( image.toLowerCase().endsWith( ".jpg" ) || image.toLowerCase().endsWith( ".jpeg" ))
            {        
                BufferedImage awtImage = ImageIO.read( new File( image ) );             
                ximage = new PDJpeg(doc, awtImage, 0 );
            }

            else
            {

                BufferedImage awtImage = new BufferedImage(250,250, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);             
                awtImage = ImageIO.read(new FileImageInputStream(new File( image )));                              
                ximage = new PDPixelMap(doc, awtImage);
            }
            System.out.println(" Width of the image.... " + ximage.getWidth());
            PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);   
            contentStream.drawImage( ximage, 20, 20);
            //contentStream.drawImage( ximage, 20, 20 );
            contentStream.close();
            doc.save( file );
       }
       finally
       {
            if( doc != null )
            {
                doc.close();
            }
       }
    }
```

NOTE:everytime the dimension of the image gets changed while saving

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: The code doesn't make sense - you're creating a BufferedImage object (awtImage), and then overwriting it with ImageIO.read(). To "prove" that something does wrong, compare awtImage.getWidth() with ximage.getWidth().

Answer (score 0):

These code may be hepful to you.

```
    public void createPDFFromImage(String pdfFile, 
        List<String> imgList,int x, int y, float scale) throws IOException, COSVisitorException {
    // the document
    PDDocument doc = null;
    try {
        doc = new PDDocument();
        Iterator iter = imgList.iterator();
        int imgIndex=0;
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
            PDPage page = new PDPage();
            doc.addPage(page);

            BufferedImage tmp_image = ImageIO.read(new File(iter.next().toString()));
            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(tmp_image.getWidth(), tmp_image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);        
            image.createGraphics().drawRenderedImage(tmp_image, null);

            PDXObjectImage ximage = new PDPixelMap(doc, image);

            imgIndex++;


            PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(
                    doc, page,true,true);

            contentStream.drawXObject(ximage, x, y, ximage.getWidth()*scale, ximage.getHeight()*scale);

            contentStream.close();
        }
        doc.save(pdfFile);
    } finally {
        if (doc != null) {
            doc.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of adding identical answers to multiple questions, please post that answer only once and add references to the other questiond pointing to your answer. (cf.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728606/pdfbox-issue-with-generating-pdf-from-a-image/22318681#22318681)