# Text replace with Image in Apache PDFBOX

Tags: pdfbox

Can anyone help me out how to replace text with Image by using Apache PDFBOX ?

Comment: Your question isn't really clear. Do you want redacting, i.e. "blacken out" stuff? Or put an image, e.g. a logo on top of an existing PDF?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr How can we to redact i.e. "blacken out" stuff in pdf using PDFBox?

Comment: @MaciejMatys it's not possible out of the box. One idea would be to analyse the content stream, replace the characters with 0, and draw black boxes over it. And what's really tricky is that a word to be blackened might be only a part of a token. So in a way, this is similar to the problem "Why was the ReplaceText example removed"? https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.File;    
import java.io.IOException;    
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;           
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;    
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;    
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject; 

public class RubberImagePaste {    
    public void createPDFFromImage( String inputFile, String imagePath, String outputFile )
            throws IOException
    {
        // the document
        PDDocument doc = null;
        try
        {
            doc = PDDocument.load( new File(inputFile) );

            PDPage page = doc.getPage(0);

            // createFromFile is the easiest way with an image file
            // if you already have the image in a BufferedImage, 
            // call LosslessFactory.createFromImage() instead
            PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile(imagePath, doc);
            PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, true, true);

            // contentStream.drawImage(ximage, 20, 20 );
            // better method inspired by http://stackoverflow.com/a/22318681/535646
            // reduce this value if the image is too large
            float scale = 1f;
            contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, 20, 20, pdImage.getWidth()*scale, pdImage.getHeight()*scale);

            contentStream.close();
            doc.save( outputFile );
        }
        finally
        {
            if( doc != null )
            {
                doc.close();
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * 
     *
     * @param args The command line arguments.
     *
     * @throws IOException If there is an error parsing the document.
     */
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
        String documentFile = "D:/ABC.pdf";
        String stampFile = "D:/Sign.png";
        String outFile = "D:ABCnew.pdf";

        new File("target/test-output").mkdirs();

        String[] args1 = new String[] { documentFile, outFile, stampFile };
        RubberImagePaste rubberStamp = new RubberImagePaste();
        rubberStamp.createPDFFromImage( documentFile, stampFile, outFile);
    }

    /**
     * This will print the usage for this example.
     */
    private void usage()
    {
        System.err.println( "Usage: java "+getClass().getName()+" <input-pdf> <output-pdf> <image-filename>" );
    }
}
```

Special Thanks to Tilman

Comment: In contrast to the question text, the text is not *replaced* by an image but merely *covered* by it.

Comment: Example above will place image at a certain location in page 0. You can change the location and page

Comment: Thus, your image may be positioned over some text and so hide it, but the text is still there and can be extracted using copy&paste. The OP asked for *replacing the text* which strictly speaking includes *removing* it.

Comment: You are correct. My solution is partially satisfying. Please share if you have a better solution. Thank you.

Comment: *My solution is partially satisfying* - it completely depends on the use case. If the PDF merely is to be printed afterwards, your solution is sufficient as copy&paste is no issue then. If the OP actually attempts redaction, it is not sufficient at all. Unfortunately the OP has not yet clarified in response to @Tilman's comment.

Comment: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/tags/1.5.0/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/ReplaceString.java