# How to display an image in PdfBox 2.0.3?

Tags: pdfbox

Can someone give me an example on how to display image in PDF file using Apache PDFBox 2.0.3?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look at the [pdfbox examples directory in the Apache SVN repository](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/), in particular the aptly named example class [AddImageToPDF](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/AddImageToPDF.java?view=markup#l45) with this pivotal method:

```
public void createPDFFromImage( String inputFile, String imagePath, String outputFile )
        throws IOException
{
    // the document
    PDDocument doc = null;
    try
    {
        doc = PDDocument.load( new File(inputFile) );

        //we will add the image to the first page.
        PDPage page = doc.getPage(0);

        // createFromFile is the easiest way with an image file
        // if you already have the image in a BufferedImage, 
        // call LosslessFactory.createFromImage() instead
        PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile(imagePath, doc);
        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, AppendMode.APPEND, true);

        // contentStream.drawImage(ximage, 20, 20 );
        // better method inspired by http://stackoverflow.com/a/22318681/535646
        // reduce this value if the image is too large
        float scale = 1f;
        contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, 20, 20, pdImage.getWidth()*scale, pdImage.getHeight()*scale);

        contentStream.close();
        doc.save( outputFile );
    }
    finally
    {
        if( doc != null )
        {
            doc.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, when i used local image path it is working fine, when i put online path of image(http://www.foodnavigator.com/var/plain_site/storage/images/publications/food-beverage-nutrition/foodnavigator.com/science-nutrition/high-cost-of-fruit-and-vegetables-linked-to-higher-body-fat-in-young-children-study/8800391-3-eng-GB/High-cost-of-fruit-and-vegetables-linked-to-higher-body-fat-in-young-children-Study.jpg) then it will not showing image. please suggest me what should i do.

Comment: @Manojkumar please share the result PDF. If your code is different than the one above, please create a new question.

Comment: String imageUrls="F:/me.png";
               String imageUrls="www.foodnavigator.com/var/plain_site/storage/images/publications/food-beverage-nutrition/foodnavigator.com/science-nutrition/high-cost-of-fruit-and-vegetables-linked-to-higher-body-fat-in-young-children-study/8800391-3-eng-GB/High-cost-of-fruit-and-vegetables-linked-to-higher-body-fat-in-young-children-Study.jpg";
                PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile(imageUrls, document);
                contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, margin+5, texty , 170, 100);

Comment: Well, that method is called `createFromFile`, so it is plausible that it creates a `PDImageXObject` from the local file system only. For other sources which you do not want to cache in the file system, please retrieve them as streams or `byte` arrays and use the appropriate methods in `JPEGFactory`, `CCITTFactory`, or `LosslessFactory` (in combination with `ImageIO`).

Comment: @Manojkumar hint in case you're new to java: use `new URL("http://.....").openStream()` (don't forget the http) to get a stream from an URL. This stream you can use with `JPEGFactory.createFromStream()`. Don't forget to close the stream after the job is done.